# Why doesn't my C program have a jmp esp instruction in the binary?

Tags: c, assembly, gdb, exploit, objdump

Why can you find `jmp esp` only in big applications?

In this little program you cant find `jmp esp`. But why? 
This is the source code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    char buffer[64];

    printf("Type in something: ");
    gets(buffer);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What there probably is is some kind of `ret` instruction. Which pops the return address from the stack. Which is how you make the program jump to your exploit: By overwriting the stack so the return address on the stack is what you put there.

Comment: Put that in a function you call.

Comment: There is no x86 machine instruction whose assembly notation is literally `jmp esp`.  There is an instruction whose assembly notation is `jmp dword ptr [esp]` in Intel-ese (encoded as 0xFF 0x24 0x24), and your `grep` would have found that if it had been generated, but I cannot think of any circumstances where a C compiler would ever generate that instruction.  Where did you read or hear that you should look for this instruction?

Comment: I read it in a book. In other bof applications this worked...

Comment: @bitfriends What is the name of this book, who wrote it, and what is its publication date?

Comment: @tadman In the code shown, the return from `main` would be exploitable, assuming no compiler mitigations (e.g. stack canaries).

Comment: Its a book in german: Hacking und Security by Rheinwerk verlag. Its from 2018

Comment: @bitfriends This book: https://www.rheinwerk-verlag.de/hacking-security_4382/ ?

Comment: Yes, this book.

Comment: Thanks.  I regret to say I cannot afford to pay € 44,90 just to find out whether the book really says buffer overflows involve a `jmp esp` instruction.  My guess, though, is that you are taking its description of how function returns work on x86 a little too literally.  The instruction you should be looking for is spelled `ret`.

Comment: Ok. So the payload will look like this: ```send = "\x41"*65 + ret adress + payload``` Or am i wrong?

Comment: If you really want to learn how to make exploits like this, you first of all need to learn the assembly language of the target platform.

Comment: Ok, i will do that. But can you help me nevertheless?

Comment: @MichaelPetch I believe you are talking about the difference between the machine instruction 0xFF 0x24 0x24 and the machine instruction 0xFF 0x2C 0x24.  On my computer, the former disassembles as `jmp dword ptr [esp]` and the latter as `jmp fword ptr [esp]`.  `jmp esp` is actually accepted without complaint by my assembler, but produces the machine instruction 0xE9 0xFC 0xFF 0xFF 0xFF with a relocation for `esp` -- that is, near relative jump to the _symbol_ `esp`.  I didn't mention that earlier because I thought it would just confuse OP even further.

Comment: @zwol: The OP is looking for a byte-sequence that in AT&T syntax is `jmp *%esp`, to use as a target for an overwritten return-address (to defeat stack ASLR for an executable payload on the stack, assuming an executable stack).  Aka a "ROP gadget".  See my answer on [Why JMP ESP instead of directly jumping into the stack](//security.stackexchange.com/q/157478) on security.SE.  The regex `jmp.*esp`  does match AT&T `jmp *%esp` or Intel-syntax `jmp esp`.  But it misses the possibility of finding this `ff e4` 2-byte instruction inside the bytes that decode as a different instruction.

Answer (score 2):

**AT&T `jmp *%esp`  /  Intel `jmp esp` has machine code `ff e4`**.  You should be looking for that byte sequence at any offset.
(I assembled a .s with that instruction and used `objdump -d` to get the machine code.)

There is a lot of discussion in comments from people who thought you were talking about
`jmp *(%esp)` as a `ret` without pop.  For future readers, see [Why JMP ESP instead of directly jumping into the stack](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/157478/why-jmp-esp-instead-of-directly-jumping-into-the-stack) on security.SE for more about this **ret2reg** technique to defeat stack ASLR when trying to return to your executable payload.  (But not defeating non-executable stacks, so this is rarely useful on its own in modern systems.)  It's a special case of a ROP gadget.

---

**Compilers are never going to use that instruction intentionally, so you'll only ever find it as part of the bytes for another instruction, or in a non-code section.  Or not at all if no data happens to include it.**

Also, your search method could miss it if it did occur.

`objdump | grep 'jmp.*esp'` is not good here.  That will miss `ff e4` as part of `mov eax, 0x1234e4ff` for example.  And disassembly of data sections similarly will only "check" bytes where objdump decides that an instruction starts.  (It doesn't do overlapping disassembly starting from every possible byte address; it gets to the end of one instruction and assumes the next instruction starts there.)

---

But even so, I compiled your code with gcc8.2 with optimization disabled (`gcc -m32 foo.c`) and searched for `e4` bytes in the output of `hexdump -C`.  None of them were preceded by an `ff` byte.  (I tried again with `gcc -m32 -no-pie -fno-pie foo.c`, still no ff e4)

**There's no reason to *expect* that to appear in a tiny executable**.

You could introduce one with a global `const unsigned char jmp_esp[] = { 0xff, 0xe4 };`

But note that modern toolchains (like late 2018 / 2019) put even the `.rodata` section in a non-executable segment.  So you'd need to compile with `-zexecstack` for byte sequences in non-code sections to be useful as gadgets.

But you probably need `-z execstack` or something else to make the stack itself executable, for your payload itself to be in an executable page, not just a `jmp esp` in a `const` array.

---

If you disabled library ASLR, then you could use an `ff e4` at a known address somewhere in libc.  But with normal randomization of library mapping addresses, it's probably just as easy to try to guess the stack address of your buffer directly, +- some bytes you fill with a NOP slide.  (Unless you can get the program you're attacking to leak a library address, defeating ASLR).

Comment: @bitfriends: that's a gcc option.  I said *compile* with, not debug with.  Also, my desktop has GDB version 8.2.1.  What kind of ancient system are you using with GDB 3?  But anyway, if your GCC + `ld` aren't from the last year or so, `.section .rodata` already gets linked into the (executable) text segment.  But you would still need `-z execstack` for the stack itself to be executable for your actual payload to run, not just the ret2reg gadget.

Comment: @bitfriends: That's a really ancient gcc version.  gcc4.x was current for a long time, but 3 is very old.  Anyway, if your linker is as old as your compiler, you don't need `-z execstack` to make a `const` array executable, it already is.  (But your stack normally won't be.)